# The order of partial derivatives on a symbolic function

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I was wondering if it is possible to get the partial derivative of a symbolic function while maintaining the same order of derivation.

Here is what I get when I plug the following command:

```
f = c[r, z]
f = c[r, z]
D[D[f, z, r], r] /. Derivative[id__][f_][args__] :> 
     TraditionalForm[
        Inactive[D][f, Sequence @@ (DeleteCases[Transpose[{{args}, {id}}], 
                {_, 0}] /. {x_, 1} :> x)]]
```

What I'm getting is $\dfrac{\partial^3c}{\partial r^2\partial z}$, even though it is supposed to be $\dfrac{\partial ^3c}{\partial r\partial z\partial r}$.

So, is there a way to do this derivation while maintaining the order of the partial derivatives?

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your code for readability to avoid special formatting. See also [How to copy code from MMA so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: In *Mathematica* `D` gets converted to `Derivative` which retains no information on the order in which the derivatives were taken.  You'll have to define your own function `myD` with its own formatting.